# IR emitter to keep TV on

Tags: circuit-design, infrared, remote-control

We installed some TVs in the main floor of our facility. We have personnel here from 8am until 12am, and the TVs have been set to turn on at 7am and off at 1am. Sometime during the day, YouTubeTV asks "Are You Still There?", and the video is paused during this prompt. Suspecting the remotes are bound to get lost, they aren't left out for someone to acknowledge the prompt, and eventually the app stops and the TV screensaver takes over.

Can I record, on an oscilloscope, some key presses from the remote with a photoresistor, and play those back with a small circuit? We have sections of drop ceiling in our facility. I could place the circuitry above the ceiling tiles close enough to the TVs, and still maintain line of sight.

Pressing the up arrow shows the video progress bar. Without any interaction, that goes away after ten seconds or so. I think replaying the up arrow once an hour would be sufficient.

The IR blasters I've seen only replay incoming signals from a remote, not pre-recorded signals.

If a device like I describe already exists, can someone tell me the terminology to google?

Comment: up arrow may control volume which could be ok.  Yes you can send IR codes  by copy store and resend.with timer.

Comment: All they intend to do is play CNN, BBC, *etc* through YouTubeTV. AFAIK, with no other activity (none expected), the up arrow only shows the progress bar. If I do volume up on the remote, that may send the input to the TV, and not the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is absolutely doable.  In fact, depending on the TV, you might not even need to record the sequence because you can just look it up.

Lots of sites like [THIS](http://irdb.tk/find/) exist, that have databases of IR codes.  All you need is a small µC to send out the pattern and the IR LED, resistor, and a transistor.

The circuit itself could be as simple as this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftw5Ig.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Just send the sequence out the I/O pin of your controller however often you need.

Comment: Thanks. Is "µC" "µController" or "µComputer". I'm thinking the former. I have to admit, emitting IR signals is very new to me. I have limited experience with Arduinos and ParticleIO boards. It seems like it should be easy enough to do though.

Comment: It is short for microcontroller.  A very simple and basic one can do the job.  Something newbie friendly could work too, like an Arduino or a Raspberry Pi.  Neither of those would cost much, and would be easy to adapt to this purpose.

Comment: I'm comfortable using RPis. We already plan on using some RPis to show static web content on some different TVs. These'd be within LoS of the smart TVs showing YTTV. Thanks.

Comment: Perfect, you can have this project done in no time then.  Note that I added a schematic to my answer in case you needed guidance on how exactly to hook it up.  Let us know if you need help calculating the correct resistor or MOSFET.